# How to update changed field controls in asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a big form which contains almost 40 controls including text area , text box, calendar control. the data in form is getting populated from database. There is option to update the details of the form. I have to save only the changed controls.

Also I have to maintain track like which users has updated which fields.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Please, share some data and ask a question, not a user requirement

Answer (score 0):

Two Methods:

1. You can use onchange function to detect the value of which controls have been changed.
   But, some user can just click on the text box but not change the value. In that case, use 2nd method.
2. Find default value of the control set from DB during load & compare it with updated field value by the user. every control has the different field where it stores default values, you will have to check it out.

Comment: Hi, How can I set default value of the control from db.